# Can't Load Image From Data Source in Infragistics Report

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, webforms, visual-studio-2013, infragistics

I have an ASP.NET WebForms project with an Infragistics report (v14.1 in VS 2013, .NET Framework 4.0). I have two data sources in the report (.igr file). The first is for report data and the second is for a company logo, all stored in SQL Server.

My second data source uses the query: `SELECT LogoImage FROM dbo.CompanyLogo WHERE CompanyId = @CompanyId`. The `CompanyId` parameter is a dynamic values list based on a member/field in the first data source.

The logo is displayed in the header and the Image property is set to `=First(Fields.LogoImage, DataSources.CompanyLogoDataSource)`. The problem is that the loaded image always uses the default value of the `CompanyId` parameter. If I don't set a default value, then the report doesn't load and shows the error "Invalid value for report parameter CompanyId." in the browser.

However, I know that the CompanyId is valid since it's used in the rest of the report and I can verify its value. Also note that only a single record is loaded in the first data source (based on a SQL view), but it is not feasible to include the image (byte array) in the view at this time. How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you cannot cascade parameters in the way I hoped. You still have to set their values when creating the report viewer.

```
$(function () {
        $("#viewer").igReportViewer({
            width: 1600,
            height: 1200,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            parameters: [{ Key: 'ReportId', Value: '<%= _reportId %>' }],
            renderSettings: {
                definitionUri: '<%= _definitionUri%>',
                serviceEndpointUri: serviceEndpoint
            }
        });
    });
```

I already had the parameter `ReportId` used for the first data source that returned the `CompanyId`. Rather than add the additional `CompanyId` to the parameters dictionary above (which would have had to be set in the code behind somehow, then sent back into the function used for the second data source), I decided to create a public IEnumerable function to return logos based on the `ReportId`. The second data source now uses this function along with the `ReportId` originally provided.